# How to ignore certain filename patterns in `find-file`/`counsel-find-file`?

Tags: ivy, counsel

When using stock `find-file` or `counsel-find-file`, is there a way to ignore certain files that I almost never want to open by hand? Examples include `.elc` files and backups.

Comment: Option **`completion-ignored-extensions`** doesn't work in that context? That's what ordinary `file-name-completion` respects. See (elisp)[File Name Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Completion.html) and (emacs)[Completion Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html). Of course, that's just extensions...

Comment: If you customize `counsel-find-file-ignore-regexp`, one of the options is to use `completion-ignored-extensions`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use `counsel-find-file-ignore-regexp`.

For the simple example you provide use

```el
    (setq counsel-find-file-ignore-regexp "\\.elc\\'")
```

The are more examples in the docstring for that variable.

Comment: Can we ignore certain folder paths as well?

Comment: To ignore paths, check `counsel-file-jump-args` - this gives a lot of control over what is found in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

While `counsel-find-file-ignore-regexp` can be used to exclude filenames, you can configure the find command to exclude paths with greater control as it has all the options available to `find`.

For example, this command excludes `__pycache__` and directories beginning with a `.` including `.git` & `.mypy_cache`.

This example finds all `*.el`, `*.org` & Makefiles, excluding `.*` (`.git` for e.g.).

```el
(setq counsel-file-jump-args 
     (list "."
           "-not" "-path"  "*/\\.*"
           "-not" "-path" "./*__pycache__/*"
           "(" "-name" "*.el" "-o" "-path" "*.org" "-o" "-path" "**/Makefile" ")"
           "-type" "f"
           "-print"))
```

You can experiment in the command line to check which files will be found:

```
find . -not -path './*__pycache__/*' \
       -not -path '*/\\.*' \
     "(" -name "*.el" -o -path "*.org" -o -path "**/Makefile" ")" \
     -type "f" -print
```